# Expressions in literals - Pass SObject to a aura component with dynamic field value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute

I've created a component which accepts as an attribute an SObject. When I simply pass a JSON SObject to it, like:

```
 <c:ChildCreatorComponent obj="{
                                    sobjectType : 'Contact',
                                    LastName : 'Rossi',
                                    FirstName : 'Mario'
                                }" />
```

Everything is fine. But right now, I need to pass a dynamic value (like an ID):

```
<c:ChildCreatorComponent obj="{
                                    sobjectType : 'Contact',
                                    AccountId : MY_DYNAMIC_ID,
                                    LastName : 'Rossi',
                                    FirstName : 'Mario'
                                }" />
```

If I try to insert my ID with an expression, as I would do in Visualforce, I obtain an error. Example:

```
<c:ChildCreatorComponent obj="{
                                        sobjectType : 'Contact',
                                        AccountId : {!v.recordId},
                                        LastName : 'Rossi',
                                        FirstName : 'Mario'
                                    }" />
```

"Cannot mix expression and literal string in attribute value, try rewriting like {!'foo' + v.bar}: Source"

But if I do that, I am passing a String instead of an SObject to the component.
Any idea? I want to keep the simplest as possible the component attribute structure.. So I can not create other attribute for the dynamic field values.

Comment: the obj is an attribute in your case and not a HTML markup and hence you get an error .What is your use case here ?

Comment: What is your code when you change to {!'foo' + v.bar}? maybe you can pass another variable?

Comment: @ItaiShmida My code is more or less this:  <c:ChildCreatorComponent obj="{!' \'sobjectType\' : \'Contact\','+
                               '\'AccountId\' : '+v.recordId+','+
                               '\'LastName\' : \'Rossi\','+
                               '\'FirstName\' : \'Mario\' '
                               }"  />  Main problem: that's a string and not an object, so the system return me a generic "Unexpected Error"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a workaround in the end. I added a String attribute to my component, called "lookups", format like this: "fieldName1:value1;fieldName2:value2...".
I use some code to read the values and write it in the object.

You can check the entire code here:

https://github.com/fracarma/Lightning-Object-Creator-Component